# Live image cropping with js+php

Tags: php, javascript, image, crop

I'd like to have ability to resize pictures on my site.
Algorithm:

1. You upload an image to site. (grey)
2. That image appears in orange part.
3. Red part - is a rectangular, with help of which we can choose which part of image to show in preview_zone.
4. After I choose right zone, I press OK and data(resize zone) uploads to server.
5. Server crops image with PHP.
   [image]

Maybe you could find any articles, how to do it, or sites with such api.
Or do it by yourselves. 
I would be very gratefule for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should check out JCrop jQuery image cropping plugin:

http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

Repo: https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop
https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/tree/master/demos

Examples: http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php

One of the demos seems to match your requirement. (http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=live_crop) You can make small modifications to get your desired output.

Comment: Is this responsive ?